# Information about Easy Pay2 Api

Tags: payment-gateway, payment

I have to integrate my website with Easy Pay2 payment gateway.
I am not able to find any information regarding Easy Pay2.
please provide me Api information for Easy Pay2 payment gateway.
please help.